# for loop exits after putting first number into array

Tags: c++

I have a small program that asks for a length of an array and asks for numbers to put into the array positions. So far it asks for array length, and lets me enter the first number but then bugs out with exited with non-zero status.

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
  int i;
  std::cout << "array length: ";
  std::cin >> i;
  int* myAarray = new int[i];
  for(int e=0, myArray; e<=i; e++){
      std::cout << "Number to put in:";
      int a;
      std::cin >> a;
      myArray[&e] = a;
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Edit: Typed my variable names in wrong, thanks for the help!

Comment: You are not deleting the array! Use std::vector instead of plain arrays to avoid such problems

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just started to learn c++ yesterday (as in just installed codeblocks) and have no idea what im doing generally!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop

```
  for(int e=0, myArray; e<=i; e++){
      std::cout << "Number to put in:";
      int a;
      std::cin >> a;
      myArray[&e] = a;
  }
```

is wrong.

The valid loop could like like

```
  for ( int e = 0; e < i; e++ ){
      std::cout << "Number to put in:";
      int a;
      std::cin >> a;
      myArray[e] = a;
  }
```

I suppose that the pointer is defined like

```
int* myArray = new int[i];
```

instead of

```
int* myAarray = new int[i];
```

that is it has name myArray.

Comment: if I do that then I get "error: 'myArray' was not declared in this scope
       myArray[e] = a;"

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow Good catch on the typo in the variable name.